# How to determine JAVA_HOME on Debian/Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, java

On Ubuntu it is possible to have multiple JVMs at the same time. The default one is selected with `update-alternatives`. But this does not set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, due to a [debian policy](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/java-common/+bug/364794).

I am writing a launcher script (bash), which starts a java application. This java application needs the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. So how to get the path of the JVM which is currently selected by `update-alternatives`?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

For the JRE, something like this should do the trick:

```
JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
```

Comment: I needed the home of the JDK instead of the JRE, but I got this using: JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed "s:bin/javac::")

Thank You!

Comment: when I tried the command `echo $(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")`, the output was `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/` and not `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/`

Comment: Code given in [**rsaddey**](http://serverfault.com/questions/143786/how-to-determine-java-home-on-debian-ubuntu#276221) works correctly

Comment: You are a scholar and a gentleman.

Comment: If someone is curious how `sed` works here: It replaces `bin/java` with an empty string. (Here `:` is used for `sed` separator instead of the usual `/`)

Answer (score 52):

danadam's solution can easily be adopted to retrieve the JDK (i.e. not JRE) path as required:

```
JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed "s:/bin/javac::")
```

- Looks for javac Java compiler (instead of java) included in JDK (but not JRE).
- Has no trailing / (stripped off by sed s:/bin... instead of s:bin...)

Comment: results in `/usr` for me on late model Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 15):

`export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f  /usr/bin/java)))`

In `.bashrc` was handy for me.

Answer (score 11):

So, you're saying that this command does nothing for you?

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: Is that suppose to set your JAVA_HOME? I've found that update-java-alternatives is a better way to update Java as update-alternatives doesn't update all Java related alternatives. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/141791/

Comment: True, but I have encountered instances of Linux that had update-alternatives but did not have update-java-alternatives installed.

Answer (score 3):

I installed java with

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

and then to find the location

```
ls -al /etc/alternatives/java
```

Answer (score 2):

As an extension of danadams answer:

First of all, install the 2nd Java JRE as the 3rd java option, with priority of "3":

```
sudo alternatives --install /usr/lib/jvm/jre jre /opt/IBM/java/jre/bin/java 3
```

Then, you can list them:

```
update-alternatives --list java
```

You can set the alternative by hand , using this:

```
sudo alternatives --config java /opt/IBM/java/jre/bin/java
```

Then, your script can set it on the fly, like so:

```
sudo alternatives --set java /opt/IBM/java/jre/bin/java
JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
```

This better illustrates what the 'sed' command is doing.   Although you still need to set the links for javaw and javac, etc, as well, each done separately.

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I created a tutorial on the Ubuntu forum on how to install the latest JRE/JDK from the Java website. It also covers on how to enable it system-wide, by adding the JRE/JDK location to the PATH variable. If you like, you can also add JAVA_HOME to the script, mentioned at the end of the topic.

Check it out:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1437100

Answer (score 1):

If java is configured with `update-alternatives` or was added to your PATH variable manually, then no hardcoded `"/usr/bin/java"` is needed. I use this solution in my .bashrc:

`export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -m $(which java)/../..)`